# arrivalRate lower than 1 using Artillery

Tags: load-testing, artillery

I am trying to design load tests using Artillery on a computation-heavy API which typically requires at least a few seconds to send a response.

Starting from examples found in the [docs](https://www.artillery.io/docs/guides/getting-started/writing-your-first-test#load-phases), I was able to run some tests such as this one:

```
config:
  target: "https://example.com/api"
  phases:
    - duration: 60
      arrivalRate: 1
      name: Base case
```

I'd now like to send requests even slower (e.g. 1 every 5 seconds) but it seems that this [cannot be done](https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/issues/279) using the arrivalRate parameter. Is there any way to do it that the docs do not mention?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How can I customize interval time of virtual user creation?](https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/issues/724)

> You can do that with arrivalCount which spreads the creation of
> virtual users evenly over a period of time (whereas arrivalRate is
> always per-second). E.g.:

```
config:
  phases:
    - duration: 60
      arrivalCount: 12
```